# Basic Rails Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a totally a beginner question. I'm embarrassed to be asking it, but here goes.

We have two models: `Person` and `Order`.

`Person` has attributes `:first_name, :last_name, :age`. `Order` has one attribute, `:total`.

`Person` `has_many :orders`, and `Order` `belongs_to :person`.

Let's assume that some data has been entered for both models.

Now, we play test this relationship in console:

```
p = Person.first 
o = Order.new(total: 100)
o.person = p # this is equivalent to: o.person_id = p.id, yes?
o.save
p.orders
```

My questions stem from line 3 and line 5.

- Question 1: Why do we have to say `o.person` instead of `o` in line 3?
- Question 2: Why are we saying `p.orders` in line 5?
- Question 3: What does this, `o.person_id = p.id`, mean exactly? I'm assuming it's associating the tables with each other?

Let me know if this question is unclear.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: An order is not a person, so you can't really say order = person.
A person belonging to an order is a person, so you have to say order.person = person

Comment: `o.person = p # this is equivalent to: o.person_id = p.id, yes?` , No that is not the case. Order does not have a person attribute.

Answer (score 2):

> Question 1: Why do we have to say "o.person instead of o" in line 3?

`Order` belongs to a `Person`, so on that line you specify the exact person who owns that order `o` by typing `o.person = p`. `o = p` doesn't make any sense.

> Question 2: And why are we saying "p.orders" in line 5?

Because each `Person` has many orders, so you can get them by typing `p.orders`

> Question 3: Also, what does this "o.person_id = p.id" mean exactly? I'm assuming it's associating the tables with each other?

Yes, this sets the owner of the order.

Ah, I see additional question:

> o.person = p (this is equivalent to: o.person_id = p.id, yes?)

Not always, but in most cases. Say, for polymorphic associations it will not only set `id`, but also a `type`.

Answer (score 2):

> Question 1: Why do we have to say "o.person instead of o" in line 3?

When you declared that an Order object `belongs_to :person`, rails created a column in the Orders table called `person_id`.  In the Orders table, the column names are the attributes of an Order object, and you refer to the attributes of an Order object using dot notation, e.g. `o.total`.

As a convenience, rails lets you assign the whole Person object to an Order attribute named `person`, then rails extracts the Person id, and rails inserts the id into the `person_id` column in the Orders table.

Your question is sort of like asking, why you have to write:

```
o.total = 10
```

instead of

```
o = 10
```

The last line does not tell rails what column in the Orders table that the value should go in.

A table is just a grid of column names and values:

```
Orders:

id     total    person_id   timestamp1   timestamp2

1       10         1          1234567     4567890
2       30         3          12342134    1324123423
3       20         1          1341234324  12341342344
```

Then if you write:

```
o = Order.find(2)
```

Then o will be assigned an Order object whose values for total, person_id, timestamp1, and timestap2, will be the values in the row where the id is equal to 2.

Next, if you write:

```
o = 10
```

What does that mean?  Does it mean that all columns for o's row should be set to the value 10?  Set the first column to 10?  Set the last column to 10?  Isn't it much clearer to write o.person = 10?

> Question 2: And why are we saying "p.orders" in line 5?

That retrieves all the orders associated with a Person object--remember you declared that a Person object `has_many` Orders.  Once again, that is a convenience provided by Rails--not declaring the associations would force you to write:

```
target_person_id = 1
@orders = Order.where(person_id: target_person_id)
```

> Question 3: Also, what does this "o.person_id = p.id" mean exactly?
>   I'm assuming it's associating the tables with each other?

`p` is a Person object, e.g. one of these rows:

```
People:

id    first      last   middle   order_id      timestamp1   timestamp2

1      Tom       Thumb    T         1            4567890       1234456
2      Wizard      Id     of        3           1324123423     123434
3      Tom       Thumb    T         2            2134234       1234234
```

If p is a Person object created from the the last row of values, then p.id is equal to 3, which means that the line:

```
o.person_id = p.id
```

is equivalent to:

```
o.person_id = 3
```

Next, o is an Order object, and the Orders table has a column named `person_id` which was created when you declared: `belongs_to: person`, and the line:

```
o.person_id = 3
```

instructs rails to insert 3 for the value of o's `person_id` column. If o's id is 1, then you get this:

```
Orders:

    id     total    person_id   timestamp1   timestamp2  

=>  1       10         3 <=       1234567     4567890
    2       30         3          12342134    1324123423
    3       20         1          1341234324  12341342344
```